# Cross domain issue for Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I am new to Javascript/jQuery. Can we call web service through jQuery Ajax for cross domain. If yes how?

When I am trying to call it is giving access denied error.

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Whats your scenario. What have you tested? First google hit: [cross domain ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Comment: If you provide the code you have tried. One way around this is to use ```JSONP```

Comment: Additionaly, you can set `crossDomain:true` in options to your `$.ajax` call (preferably using `JSONP`). Please read the [$.ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: function CallWebService() {var val1 = document.getElementById("txtNo").value; $.ajax({ type: "post",crossDomain: true,url: "http://SiteName/Student.asmx/GetStudentDetails", data: "{'studNumber'='" + val1 + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "JSONP",Success: function (result) {alert(val1); OnSuccess(result); },error: function (xhr, status, error) {OnFailure(error);} });} function OnSuccess(result) {
            if (result) {alert(result);     }
        }
        function OnFailure(error) {
            alert(error);
        }